# Sqlite trigger to calculate an ID based on an entry type

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to setup a trigger that will auto calculate an ID field based on the sum of a specific type of entry. I have it working where the ID number in the ID indexes based on the number of all entries

```
>     BEGIN
>         UPDATE master_workorders
>         SET wo_no = master_workorders.wo_sub || substr('0000'||master_workorders.pkuid, -4,4)||'-'|| substr(master_workorders.rdate,3,2)
>         WHERE rowid = NEW.rowid;
>     END
```

This returns ID's like WO0001-17 BB0002-17 and M0003-17 each ID number (middle 4 digits) is an entry. I want my ID numbers to represent the number of each type (WO, BB, M these values are stored in the wo_sub column) as WO0001-17 BB0001-17 M0001-17 and if a new BB work order is added it would be BB0002-17 and so on for each type.

Comment: That is not valid SQL. Show some example data.

Comment: It is valid, it doesn't do exactly what I want but it does concatenate the wo_sub field with the pkuid field, padded with zeros, with the last 2 digits of the year from the rdate field into a new field looking similar to WO0001-17. Explain please how that is invalid?

Comment: `Error: near "substr": syntax error`

Comment: I get no errors in; Navicat, SQLitestudio, LibreOffice, QGIS, or Qspatialite, when I add new records the trigger fires and I get exactly what I expect to in the wo_no field. I noticed only Navicat shows the SQL with "BEGIN" and "END". Anyway, I don't understand how it can work for me and not for you. I even checked it again to see if I miscopied something but I am not seeing it. This is also only the code that fires within the trigger it is not the code to make a trigger. Does it work with a create trigger statement added to the beginning?

Comment: I see it now; it is missing a concatenation between master_workorders.wo_sub and substr('0000'||master_workorders.pkuid, -4,4). Will fix it in the post. Thanks

Comment: Show some example data and the desired results.

Comment: My table has 4 columns  pkuid (auto incrementing Integer), wo_no (unique identifying number), wo_sub (a 2 letter entry identifying the type of entry. Can only be WO, M, or BB), and rdate( Date field holding the date of entry formatted in YYYY-MM-DD). I want the wo_no field to reflect the number of entries with their respective wo_sub, so if I add a BB entry the wo_no will calculate to be the wo_sub, BB in this case, th total of all current BB entries in the table +1 for the record we are adding, followed by the last 2 digits of the year.

Comment: So when I create a view of all entries starting with BB I will get sequential wo_no within that sub group of entries, and so on for each other entry type like M and WO sub types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace the autoincremented ID with the current count, replace `master_workorders.pkuid` with a subquery:

```
... || (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM master_workorders WHERE wo_sub = NEW.wo_sub) || ...
```

Comment: That did it I just had to add the substring lines to get the number padded with zeros. Thanks again.